# Django cms - running the installer

Tags: django, django-cms

I am trying out the django cms. I have now tried the recipe described here: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/support-3.0.x/introduction/install_from_scratch.html very carefully, but towards the end of the installer run it fails with an exception:

```
...
raise exceptions.UnknownMigration(self, sys.exc_info())
south.exceptions.UnknownMigration: Migration 'auth:0001_initial' probably doesn't exist.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/munin-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/migration/base.py", line 313, in migration
migration = __import__(full_name, {}, {}, ['Migration'])
File "/tmp/munin-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/migrations/0001_initial.py", line 5, in <module>
from django.db import models, migrations
File "/tmp/munin-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .operations import *  # NOQA
File "/tmp/munin-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .models import (CreateModel, DeleteModel, AlterModelTable,
File "/tmp/munin-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/models.py", line 4, in <module>
from django.db.models.options import normalize_together
ImportError: cannot import name normalize_together

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/munin-cloud/venv/bin/djangocms", line 11, in <module>
  sys.exit(execute())
File "/tmp/munin-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 31, in execute
django.setup_database(config_data)
File "/tmp/munin-cloud/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djangocms_installer/django/__init__.py", line 325, in setup_database
  "manage.py", "migrate", "--fake"], env=env)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
  raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: 
Command '['/tmp/munin-cloud/venv/bin/python', '-W', 'ignore', 'manage.py', 'migrate', '--fake']' 
   returned non-zero exit status 1
```

When running `manage.pg syncdb` it reports that some of the tables have been synced, and some are not synced - use migrations. When I then run `manage.py migrate` I get the same exception again.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 - if that matters.

Comment: Hm, which version of django-cms are you using? It seems there are some problems with django versions, because it wants to import normalize_together which was introduced in django 1.7 while cms uses 1.6

Comment: Under Django 1.7, you should only need to use: `manage.py migrate` as it will perform the same actions as `syncdb` did previously.

Comment: I am using `django-cms` version "stable" which I guess is 3.0.x. Have tried both Django 1.6 and 1.7 with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I mixed up the django version in the current virtual environment and the django version configured during the django-cms install process. When I ensured that I had Django 1.6 installed and entered 1.6 during django-cms configuration it worked.